# How do I read an Expression's contents?

Tags: c#, .net, expression, linq-expressions

I have a class that works as a repository of some sort, and grants access to a database. I'm trying to customize it to allow queries with expressions.

So, I want to be able to do this:

```
IList<MyClass> myList = myRepository.GetBy(x => x.Name == "SomeName");
//and...
IList<MyClass> myList2 = myRepository.GetBy(x => x.Name == "SomeName" && x.ID = 5);
```

This is what I need to have on the repository function:

```
public IList<T> GetBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    //Set up the query, etc
    //I'm at the WHERE clause, and I need to get the property(ies) name(s) of the expression and their values to properly set the WHERE
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: What is stopping you doing `blah.Where(expression.Compile())`?

Comment: @DavidG It will be inefficient. `Compile` returns delegate, so prediction will be applied at server side - after fetching all objects from database. It would ask why don't use just `queryable.Where(expression);`

Comment: @pwas it will work, but I forgot OP was starting with IQueryable so the compile isn't needed :)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is this:
`IList <MyClass> myList2 = myRepository.GetBy (x => x.Name == "SomeName" && x.ID` = 5);
It is true that you can represent `x => x.Name == "SomeName" && x.ID = 5 with Expression <Func <T, bool >>`

but also what you can do with the delegate `Func <T, bool>` only.

Regardless of which were to take the data will always be from an `IEnumerable <T>` so you always will have the `Where` method (whenever you use the namespace `System.Linq`), which accepts as a parameter a delegate `Func <T, bool>` . If the object `IEnumerable <T>` is a `DbSet <T>`, this will take care of transforming the delegate `Func <T, bool>` in a sql query. Remember that a Linq query, which is what is being used, is only executed when the query data is used or agrees with methods `ToList ()` or `ToArray ()` for example.

example:
`IEnumerable <MyClass> list = ...` from wherever you get the data even from DbSet of EntityFramework

```
var query = list.Where (x => x.Name == "SomeName" && x.ID = 5);
```

query is a shost a query, it contains no data until this is done

```
foreach (var x in list) is being consumed, so the query is executed
{
   var c = x.Name;
}
```

or this

```
`var temp = query.ToList ();`
```

This force to stored in a `List <MyClass>`
With all this I want to say that if you use the DbSet of EntityFramework, what happens is that the delegate `Func <T, bool>` is transformed into a sql query, so that the data manager is responsible for filtering data (as it should be).
 From this alone you would have to simply have your method

```
public IList <T> GetBy (Func <T, bool> expression)
{
    origen.Where (expression).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if I understand your question correctly, you shoul inherit you repository interfaces from base generic repository interface.

```
public interface IRepositoryBase<TEntity>
{
    IList<TEntity> GetBy(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
}
```

and repository realisation from base repository implementation

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<TEntity>: IRepositoryBase<TEntity>
{
    public MyEntities EntitiesContext { get; set; }

    public IList<TEntity> GetBy(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
    {
       return EntitiesContext.Set<TEntity>().Where(filter).ToList()
    }
}
```

Comment: If he already has a query provider then he doesn't need to do *anything*.  The whole point of this question is that he doesn't have a query provider for the data source in question.